# mako access variable outside of code block

Tags: python, flask, mako

I am using Flask and Mako for some templating and was wondering if it is possible to access a defined variable outside of a code block.
In detail I want to do the following:

```
<%
   foo="bar"
%>
here is foo: ${foo}
```

the expected output would be:

> here is foo: bar

I could not get it working this way, sadly, os I am asking IF this is possible and HOW.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

in the mako template I used to do like this, ex:

python code in block

```
<%
   foo="bar"
%>
```

javascript code

```
var foo = "here is foo:"+ "${foo}";
console.log(foo);
```